# Filtering a dataframe with the row index (conditional) of another dataframe & combining that row

Tags: r, dataframe

df_1 is a test dataset. It contains players name and skills (numerical value).

```
df_1 <- data.frame(Name=c('S. Becker','A. Dabasse','S. Yesil','Jeon Se Jin','Nicholas Aldair'),
                   `Weak Foot`=c(3,3,3,4,3),
                   `Skill Moves`=c(3,2,3,3,3),
                   Crossing=c(60,29,35,51,66),
                   Finishing=c(57,59,71,65,75),
                   HeadingAccuracy=c(42,62,48,54,72),
                   ShortPassing=c(60,57,58,61,74) )


# Name              Weak.Foot   Skill.Moves Crossing  Finishing HeadingAccuracy ShortPassing
# S. Becker         3           3           60        57              42           60
# A. Dabasse        3           2           29        59              62           57
# S. Yesil          3           3           35        71              48           58
# Jeon Se Jin       4           3           51        65              54           61
# Nicholas Aldair   3           3           66        75              72           74
```

After predicting 'position' for this data using a model (multi logistic), i get the second dataframe df_2. Obviously, since this is a Logit model, they're the probabilities of being in that particular position. ( DEF FWD MID )

```
df_2 <- data.frame( DEF=c(5.73E-04,5.46E-06,2.08E-06,8.76E-06,6.56E-05),
                    FWD=c(0.4489639,0.9057274,0.9862491,0.9322038,0.8389187),
                    MID=c(0.55046347,0.09426718,0.01374878,0.06778743,0.16101569))


# DEF          FWD       MID
# 5.726046e-04 0.4489639 0.55046347
# 5.455446e-06 0.9057274 0.09426718
# 2.076482e-06 0.9862491 0.01374878
# 8.758119e-06 0.9322038 0.06778743
# 6.564988e-05 0.8389187 0.16101569
```

I need to  display only the rows of df_1 with the *index* of df_2 where values of **MID** is in the top 2, along with this MID row included.

Desired output

```
# Name              Weak.Foot   Skill.Moves Crossing  Finishing HeadingAccuracy ShortPassing  MID 
# S. Becker         3           3           60        57              42           60         0.55046347
# Nicholas Aldair   3           3           66        75              72           74         0.16101569
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
cbind(df_1,select(df_2,MID)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(MID)) %>% 
  slice(1:2)
#>              Name Weak.Foot Skill.Moves Crossing Finishing HeadingAccuracy ShortPassing       MID
#> 1       S. Becker         3           3       60        57              42           60 0.5504635
#> 2 Nicholas Aldair         3           3       66        75              72           74 0.1610157
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `order`.

```
cbind(df_1, df_2[3])[order(-df_2$MID)[1:2], ]
#              Name Weak.Foot Skill.Moves Crossing Finishing HeadingAccuracy ShortPassing       MID
# 1       S. Becker         3           3       60        57              42           60 0.5504635
# 5 Nicholas Aldair         3           3       66        75              72           74 0.1610157
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the second best value by ordering 'MID' column and accessing the second row with iloc. Then you join the two dataframes by index (I assume both DataFrames have the same order). If the indexes are not the same you can first reset them by using `df_1.reset_index(drop=True)` and `df_2.reset_index(drop=True)`.Finally you just need to apply the filter condition.

```
import pandas as pd

threshold = df_2['MID'].sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[1]
df = df_1.join(df_2['MID'])
result = df[df['MID'] >= threshold]
print(result)
```